# Perl: Return new instance of the class with the function

Tags: java, perl, function, constructor

How can I return new instance in perl, like in Java for example:

```
public AClass getAClass() {
   return new AClass();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sub getAClass {
   return new AClass();
}
```

But why do

```
my $o = AClass->getAClass();
```

instead of

```
my $o = AClass->new();
```

Comment: Thanks, I made a mistake by writing: return AClass->new();

Comment: No, I'd write it as `AClass->new()` too (as you see further down in the post). I used indirect object notation (which is usually discouraged) just to make the code nearly original to the Java you posted to subtly point out you really didn't put any effort into your question.

Comment: I have a problem, it throws me an error "Undefined subroutine &main::getAClass.." when I try to, my $t1 = AClass->new(3, 4); my $t2 = $t1.getAClass

Comment: `.` is the concatenation operator in Perl. `->` is the method invocation oprator.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid the indirect object notation. Use

```
AClass->new(...)
```

instead of

```
new AClass(...)
```

The reason is that the former always does what you expect, whereas the latter is ambiguous syntax - does it stand for the former code, or does it really mean this?

```
new(AClass(...))
```

The parser might guess the wrong intention to fix this ambiguity. So you should avoid it - use the direct arrow notation instead.